# React - how to map buttons in a list to the object they are in?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following class Component which reads data from localstorage.
The Localstorage has an array of objects. Those objects are rendered in a list as you can see below. In each list item there is a button I added in the code. If a user clicks the `<ExtendButton />` I want to extend the `{el.infoDays}` of 7 days.

Can anyone help me with that, or at least with binding the button to the object it is in, so that if a user clicks the button I will get the whole object (where the button is in) displayed in the console.log?

I tried the following, I tried with `e.target`, `this`, etc. The `onExtendBtnClick` method is not well written.

```
let uniqid = require('uniqid');


class History extends Component {
    state = {
        loans: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const rawInfos = localStorage.getItem('infos');
        const infos = JSON.parse(rawInfos);
        this.setState({
            infos: infos
        });
    }




    render() {
        const {infos} = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {infos.map((el) => (

                            <li key={uniqid()}>
                                <small>Requested date: {el.infoRequestTime}</small><br />
                                <div>
                                    <span ><em>Requested amount</em><em>{el.infoAmount} &euro;</em></span>
                                    <span><em>In days</em><em>{el.infoDays}</em></span>
                                </div>
                                <spa>Give back: {el.infoCost} &euro;</span>
                                <ExtendButton />
                            </li>

                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default History;
```

And I have also the button component:

```
class ExtendButton extends Component {

    onExtendBtnClick = () => {
        console.log(this)
    };



    render() {
        return (
            <button
                className="extend-button"
                onClick={this.onExtendBtnClick}
            >
                Extend for 1 week
            </button>
        );
    }
}

export default ExtendButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your button component take in an `onClick` prop and set that on its own internal button:

```
class ExtendButton extends Component {

    onExtendBtnClick = () => {
        this.props.onClick();
    };



    render() {
        return (
            <button
                className="extend-button"
                onClick={this.onExtendBtnClick}
            >
                Extend for 1 week
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

Then just pass an `onClick` function to your component:

```
<ExtendButton onClick={() => {console.log(el)}} />
```